# Use Python to insert data into a MS Access Database

Tags: python, sql, ms-access, pyodbc

I'm trying to insert values into a Microsoft Access Database using Python.

I'm able to insert values as follows:

```
df = pd.read_excel(xlsx, sheets[0])

for i in range(1, len(sheets)):
    data = []
    data = pd.read_excel(xlsx, sheets[i])
    df = df.append(data)

k = (df.iat[3,0])
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ= \\.....\Stat_tracker.accdb;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ABCD (Serial) VALUES ('xxxx')")

cursor.execute('select * from ABCD')
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

I want to use a loop to iterate over multiple records. Is there a better way?

When I replace the `cursor.execute` code with

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ABCD (Serial) VALUES (%s)",(k,))
```

It throws back the following error:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]
> Syntax error in query expression '%s'. (-3100) (SQLPrepare)")

Clearly, I'm missing something with the use of `%s`. Perhaps there's another placeholder?

It should be a simple fix, I'm just too unfamiliar with the syntax.

Help a newbie out?

Comment: Perhaps comma after k is an issue because there is only one parameter.

Comment: @June7, OP actually has it correct as it is a tuple of one item. OP is using the wrong placeholder. For `pyodbc`, it should be qmark, `?`.

Comment: Please show data so we can see what you are attempting to insert. Right now only one scalar value appears to be attempted.

Comment: If you really do need to use pandas then you might be interested in [sqlalchemy-access](https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-access/) to facilitate writing the DataFrame values to Access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's [Database API Specification](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) lists [several ways of doing parametrization](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle):

- `qmark`: Question mark style, e.g. `...WHERE name=?`
- `numeric`: Numeric, positional style, e.g. `...WHERE name=:1`
- `named`: Named style, e.g. `...WHERE name=:name`
- `format`: ANSI C printf format codes, e.g. `...WHERE name=%s`
- `pyformat`: Python extended format codes, e.g. `...WHERE name=%(name)s`

Most implementations only support one or maybe two. It [looks like](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) `pyodbc` uses `qmark`-style parameters, not `format`-style.

Try this instead:

```py
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ABCD (Serial) VALUES (?)", (k,))
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider a pure SQL query as MS Access Jet/ACE engine can directly query Excel workbooks. Specifically, run an insert-select `UNION` query, avoiding the use of pandas, looping, or parameters.

Below assumes `Serial` column header exists in each Excel sheet and is the column you intended to loop on. Adjust accordingly.

```
sql = """INSERT INTO ABCD (Serial)
         SELECT t1.Serial 
         FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;Database=C:\Path\To\Excel\Workbook.xlsx].[Sheet1$] t1

         UNION ALL

         SELECT t2.Serial 
         FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;Database=C:\Path\To\Excel\Workbook.xlsx].[Sheet2$] t2

         UNION ALL

         SELECT t3.Serial 
         FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;Database=C:\Path\To\Excel\Workbook.xlsx].[Sheet3$] t3

         ...
      """

cur.execute(sql)
```